# Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS VG Allotment

Tags: server, 18.04, default

Does anyone know why, on a 4TB target, Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS only allows a 4GB VG for/?

I had to run lvdisplay and then expand the VG to 100%.

I'm just curious if anyone knows why that restriction occurs by default? Maybe I selected something incorrectly during the installation process? Thanks.

Comment: What does `VG` stand for?

Comment: You probably selected G or GB instead of T / TB. You can try to boot your system from the LIVE USB you installed from and fix it with the prober LVM commands .. or simply do a reinstall and select the correct sizes.